# How to send long query (Get Request) to SharePoint to retrieve the data using PnP RestApi?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SPFx with react and using PnP RestAPI.

I am only retrieving less that 5000 records. My filter query length is too big. Below is the just example of filter query which I am sending but yes, length is big.

```
var queryGet = ID ne null and BusinessPartner eq 'Managed Information' and (BusinessUnit eq 'Engineering Software' or BusinessUnit eq 'Business MECWAVE' or BusinessUnit eq 'Business MOBIWAVE' or BusinessUnit eq 'Product Management' or BusinessUnit eq 'Business STREETWAVE & Eng. Hardware' or BusinessUnit eq 'Business Telematics & MNO Certification' or BusinessUnit eq 'Ready Secure' or BusinessUnit eq 'Aftermarket' or BusinessUnit eq 'Operations' or BusinessUnit eq 'Other') and Category eq 'Internal FTE (new)' and Country eq 'United States' and InternalOrExternal eq 'Internal' and Recommend_Controller eq 'n/a (R&D replacement in BCC)' and Recommend_HR eq 'Yes' and (Location eq 'CN_Shenzhen' or Location eq 'FR_Montigny Le Brettonneux' or Location eq 'HU_Szekesfehervar' or Location eq 'IL_Hod Hasharon' or Location eq 'JP_Nagoya' or Location eq 'NL_Amsterdam' or Location eq 'RO_Bucharest' or Location eq 'MX_Queretaro' or Location eq 'EE_Tallinn' or Location eq 'BR_Manaus' or Location eq 'BE_Brussels' or Location eq 'CN_Shenzhen') or Location eq 'CN_Shenzhen' or Location eq 'CN_Shenzhen' or Location eq 'CN_Shenzhen' or Location eq 'CN_Shenzhen' or Location eq 'CN_Shenzhen' or Location eq 'CN_Shenzhen' Location eq 'IL_Hod Hasharon' or Location eq 'JP_Nagoya' Location eq 'IL_Hod Hasharon' or Location eq 'JP_Nagoya'
const web = Web(this.props.siteURLProps);
await web.lists.getByTitle("AccountList").items.select("*, AccountRelatedTo/Title").expand("AccountRelatedTo")
        .filter(queryGet).top(4999)
```

1. This is getting failed with error - "parsers.js:130 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [404]  ::>"
2. If I remove some filter condition then it works file.

Please help into this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `renderListDataAsStream` method where you can provide your filter condition and row limit in [CAML Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema). CAML Query is another way where you can provide your filter condition in XML and as `renderListDataAsStream` is the `POST` call and your query will be passed as `Body` instead of `Query String`, there will not be any scenario of long URL:

Try below code:

```
var queryGet = '<View><Query><Where>{Filter Condition XML according to your requirement}</And></Where></Query></View>';
var response = await web.lists.getByTitle("AccountList")..renderListDataAsStream({ViewXml:queryGet})
```

If you use `renderListDataAsStream` method, then you don't need to expand any user or lookup column, this method will provide all the necessary values e.g. in case of User field, it will return user's display name, email, account name, etc.

There are some tools available using which you can build CAML Query according to your requirement:

- [CAML Query Builder for SharePoint 2013/2016/2019/Online](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/caml-query-builder-in-sharepoint-2013-online/)

**Update**

There are some helper utilities which you can use to build dynamic CMAL Query easily

- [camljs](https://github.com/andrei-markeev/camljs)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I am dynamically generating the query then passing the query string in filter condition. here dynamically generating in '<View><Query><Where>{Filter Condition XML according to your requirement}</And></Where></Query></View>'; is will very complex thing as I beleive.

Comment: I can understand that creating CAML query would be complex than REST API filter, but if you use REST API as filter then you might come up with Long URL which will not work anyway. There are couple of helper utility which will help you to build CAML Query easily. I updated my answer

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?